# How to communicate a "warning" message from the Service/DAO to the UI?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a Java web application.  It's basically something like this:

```
editUser.jsp -> ControllerServlet.java -> UpdateUserCommand.java -> UserService.java -> UserDAO.java -> USER_TABLE.db
```

The user clicks a 'Save Changes' button on the editUser.jsp page, on success, the view is redirected to the viewUser.jsp page where they are presented with a read only view of the user and a "User changes successfully saved" message is displayed.

For example, UpdateUserCommand.java does:

```
user.setWhatevers( /* whatevers */ );
try {
  user = this.userService.updateUser(user);
  messages.recordSuccessMessageForView("User changes successfully saved.");
} catch (Exception x) {
  messages.recordErrorMessageForView("There was an error; "+x.getMessage());
}
/* redirect to viewUser.jsp page */
```

My issue is, inside UserService.java I call something else -- let's say a NotificationService.java that sends an email.  If the send email fails, I log the email sending error, but I proceed normally.

The result is, the user sees the "Successully saved!" message, but there's no visible indication that the email wasn't sent.  (Even though the send email error is logged on the server.)

For example, UserService.java does:

```
public User updateUser(User user) throws Exception {
  try {

    this.userDAO.updateUser(user);

    try {
      this.notificationService.sendEmail("bob@bob.com", "user saved");
    } catch (Exception x) {
      logger.log("Error sending email; "+x.getMessage();
    }

  } catch (Exception x) {
    throw new Exception("Error saving!", x);
  }
}
```

So my question is, how would you suggest I communicate from the UserService back to the UpdateUserCommand that there is an email-related warning message to display in the UI?

UpdateUserCommand.java can easily do a:

```
messages.recordWarning("Could not send the email.");
```

But the UserService.java doesn't have access to the 'messages' object.  And I don't want the UserService to throw an exception because I want everything to proceed as if everything is normal.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

1. Have your Service method return some type that encapsulates both the `User` that it current responds and something representing notification-type messages. This solution is nicer than #2 as it's a bit easier to test.
2. Have noticiationService or some other service record it's "messages for the web user" in a ThreadLocal which you then access and clear on the UI layer. This option is a little bit uglier in that you are essentially keeping global data around (and you are assuming that one thread = one request), but it doesn't require changes to the signatures of existing methods.